# How to construct an inverse linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Problem:** Consider the linear map $L: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3: (x,y,z) \mapsto (2x+y-z, y-2z, -2x-z)$. Let $U = \text{span} \left\{(0,0,1), (1,1,1)\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear subspace of $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^3, +)$. Determine $L^{-1}(U)$.

How does one solve this? I let $\beta$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, and then computed the matrix representation $[L]_{\beta}$ of this map. But this matrix isn't invertible so that didn't help me.

How can I compute $L^{-1}$ directly on the basis of the given definition?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for a linear map?  Perhaps all you want is a description of the subspace which maps into U.

Comment: It's taken from my professor's textbook, I don't know what he is after. But let's say we have another linear map, which is invertible. How would I compute it? Do I have to find the matrix representation first?

Comment: Note that $L^{-1}(U)=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^3:L(v)\in U\}$; it doesn't mean $L$ has an inverse.

Answer (score 2):

I jumped to conclusions in my other answer, so let's try again. As you note $L$ isn't an invertible map. First note that 
$$
U = \left\{\pmatrix{x \\ x \\ z }: x, z\in \mathbb{R}\right\}.
$$
Note that
$$
L\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{2x + y -z \\  y -2z \\ -2x  -z}
$$
and that
$$
L^{-1}(U) = \{\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3: L\vec{v} \in U\}.
$$
So to find all vectors that end up in this subspace you would need exactly
$$
2x +y -z = y - 2z.
$$
The solution set to this equartion will be $L^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: Ok. But what does that have to do with $L^{-1}(U)$? How do I construct the inverse linear map?

Comment: @Kamil: $L$ isn't invertible, so there isn't an inverse map.